# Recommended approach to create custom controls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I'm learning Angularjs and there are a number of requirements to build custom components.  One of these is a date formatter - here is the sample angular module directive javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('datetime', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { value: '@value' },
        template: 
            '<span>{{value | date: "dd/MM/yyyy @ hh:mma"}}</span>'
        }
    }
);
```

which is used by the following html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in results.OpenProjects">
    <td><datetime value="{{ item.WhenCreated }}"></datetime></td>
</tr>
```

The above is working fine, but I'd like to know if I'm going about writing the controls in the way I've done.

Has anyone done this type of work and could chip in with their thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me (but I'm only learning directives now).  You can simply write "value: '@'" instead (since you're using the same name).  You might also want to include "replace: true", if you want <datetime...></datetime> to be removed from the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks.  Just also read that I should be naming my controls with a prefix of ng-

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at http://angular-ui.github.com, they've got a date picker and lots of good directives already.

Comment: Angular has pretty good documentation on Directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

The datetime directive in this scenario seems to be an overkill because it is not doing ..well..anything..

Your formatting is being done by the date filter ( which is the right place to do formatting! ).

Your datetime directive could as well be something like

```
<span>{{item.whenCreated | date: "dd/MM/yyyy @ hh:mma"}}</span>
```

Directives are meant for DOM manipulation. So, anywhere you are doing $("") in non angular scenario..use a directive.

Comment: I understand that it could be done as you say but this would cause a proliferation of formatting markup for dates across my html pages.  The reason for my approach was to localise date formatting in case a future change was required.

Comment: @dubs you could write your own date filter that would default to your preferred format (optionally allowing overriding and/or short aliases to different formats).

Comment: @Steven good call. I agree in what you're suggesting as it does seem to be a cleaner approach.  I've done this already for things like formatting 'total_days' to (for example) 9y 10m 2d.  No doubt, there'll be many others !